# ElasticSearch right use of should between musts

Tags: .net, vb.net, elasticsearch

I have to make a query with the following filtering: (1 || 2) && (4 || 5 || 6) && (6 || 7) using the must and should functionality of ElasticSearch in .NET, but I have no idea how to make the Must between the Should filtering. I looked through the tutorials and documentation, but I couldn't find example of that.
Any help is appreciated.

Can you help me with the Visual Basic representation of this? The code I got is:

```
Dim r As FilterContainer = Filter(Of view_Article).Bool(Function(b)
                      b.Should(lstAF.ToArray)
                      For Each item As ContainerList In lstAnyFilter
                          b.Should(item.list.ToArray())
                      Next
                      Return b
                      End Function)
Return r
```

But I it's just replacing the current Should filter with the new one. How to make multiple separate Should filter requests?

Answer (score 0):

You should combine bool filters:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {#FILTER1},
                  {#FILTER2}
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {#FILTER3},
                  {#FILTER4},
                  {#FILTER5}
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "should": [
                  {#FILTER6},
                  {#FILTER7}
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `bool filter` ,`bool Query` can also be used. Use it as

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "bool": {
                   "should": [
                      {Query1},
                      {Query2}
                   ]
               }
           },
           {
               "bool": {
                   "should": [
                      {Query3},
                      {Query4}
                   ]
               }   
           }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```